# I want when scrolling webview, the view above also scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, view, webview

I have a view holds some labels and view. Then I have a webview below that view.
I want to handle when scrolling webview, the view above also scrolls
That's to say, when user scroll the webview, the uiview scroll also scrolls

Thanks for any help.